# reserving memory for vector of vector, c++

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I read many questions on this topic on stackoverflow. However, I couldn't find my answer in any of them. Hence, this question.

I have

```
vector< vector< int > > temp
```

I can reserve memory for outer vector :

```
temp.reserve(20);
```

Now, I want to reserve memory for each inside vector. I can do this using:

```
temp[i].reserve(500);
```

However, if I use temp.clear(); then the capacity of temp is retained as 20.
However, now if I initialize the temp vector with 20 inner vectors, the capacity of these inner vectors is reset to 0 (according to VS2010 Intellisense).

My questions:

1. How can I retain the inner vector capacity of 500 even after I clear and re-initialize the outer vector?
2. I am using OpenCV findContours function. This function clears the outer vector and fills it with new set of inner vectors. Does this function cause deallocation and re-allocation of memory?

Comment: When you call clear(), all the inner vectors are destroyed. If you want to retain their capacity, you will have to call clear() for each inner vector.

Comment: Is it even guaranteed that `std::vector::clear` preserves the reserved capacity?

Comment: Yes, the allocated memory is not released, only the elements are destroyed and the size becomes 0.

Comment: @jamesdlin Nope that's not guaranteed at all. I worked with an implementation once that freed the memory on `clear` (although I can't remember which compiler it was).

Comment: @VoidStar: wrong, `clear()` may or may not release the memory. Actually that detail is implementation-specific. It is not mandatory in any C++ standard.

Comment: Also note that you're not allowed to do `temp[i].reserve(500)` if you just .reserve-d the "outer" vector. It does not contain any objects yet, to be allowed to call `temp[i].reserve(500)` you'd have to use resize (or alike) for the outer vector.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @VoidStar: I can retain the inner vector capacity by clearing each of them. However, the inner vectors are destroyed once the outer vector is cleared. Unfortunately, the OpenCV function (findContours) clears the outer vector. So I guess I'll have to deal with de-allocation and re-allocation of the inner vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can't in C++. Clearing the outer vector by definition destroys the inner vectors, releasing all their memory.

2) If it's clearing the outer vector and recreating it, then yes it's causing a deallocation followed by an allocation.

Unfortunately I can't make out what your underlying problem is so I can't offer any more help regarding possible solutions.

EDIT: You could always have outer be a vector of (possibly smart) pointers to inner vectors that are stored in/retrieved from a pool. Then when outer is cleared only the pointer itself is cleared and the pooled inner vector yet remains.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was particularly looking at a way to clearing and recreating the outer vector and prevent deallocation followed by reallocation of the inner vector memory. However, I thing this is not possible in C++